# How to insert a space after every 3rd character in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a column called FRUITS, ex. “Banana”, “Watermelon”, “pomegranate”

The results I’m looking for are to return

Ban ana
Wat erm elo n
Pom meg ran ate

Comment: What have you tried so far? The community is here to help, not to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(fruits, '(...)', '\1 ') As with_spaces
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (fruits) AS
SELECT 'Banana' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Watermelon' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'pomegranate' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| WITH_SPACES |
| --- |
| Ban ana |
| Wat erm elo n |
| pom egr ana te |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UvuceSdB)